# passing $scope variable into html function markup with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, syntax-error, markup

I have a ng-repeat and I want to call a function in a ng-mouseover using two parameter as follow:

```
ng-mouseover="textlimit({{item.id}}, 900)"
```

If I do that the variable appears correctly in the sources, but the console outputs an angular syntax error. My function isn't working since then I added this variable.

How should I proceed?

PS: the variable is a number: 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

Thanks

Comment: You just have to pass it as `ng-mouseover="textlimit(item.id, 900)"` Remove interpolation.

Comment: @SKYnine take a look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need of `{{}}` in `ng-mouseover` since its an angular component,

you can use the method directly like

`ng-mouseover="textlimit(item.id, 900)"`

instead of

`ng-mouseover="textlimit({{item.id}}, 900)"`

A sample example is shown below

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/63d37Lcg/)

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
   <a href="#" onclick="return false;" ng-mouseover="textlimit(item.id, 900)">Download</a>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.item = {
        id:21
    }
    $scope.textlimit = function(id, value)
    {
        console.log('id::',id);
        console.log('value::',value);
    }
});
```

Comment: ... Thanks! couldn't find anything about it.